# In Appwidget RemoteViews' setOnClickPendingIntent is not getting called after user force stops application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

Here i have made one widget and added its click listener where i'm starting one service.It works perfectly.But once user force stops application from appinfo my widget's click is not responding.I m not getting why this is happening.Help on this will be appreciated.Thank you

My app widget class code:

MyWidget.java:

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    static Context cont;
    static SharedPreferences preferences;


    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        cont = context;
        Intent intent2 = new Intent();

        intent2.setAction("....");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.
                getBroadcast(context, 0,
                        intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_widget);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.appwidget_text, pendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them

        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
                context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));

       }
  @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
..................  }
  @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
  .................}
```

Comment: Switch to using an explicit Intent (`new Intent(context, YourReceiver.class)`) instead of an implicit `Intent` (`setAction("....");`). At minimum, this will eliminate some security issues. It *might* help in this case, as an explicit `Intent` is the way to move apps out of the stopped state.

Comment: @CommonsWare - thanks..that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Always use an explicit `Intent` whenever possible. Your code would not work on Android 8.0 and higher, where implicit broadcasts are banned. And an explicit Intent can move your app out of the stopped state.